# Problema al usar acordeón de Bootstrap

Tags: html5, angular, bootstrap, css3

Tengo este problema al usar acordeón de Bootstrap , estoy importando el css y el js como debería pero no logro hacerlo funcionar bien, al picarle al link el acordeón se pasa de largo y no logra el efecto que tiene que tener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen esta abierto el primer acordeón, y miren como el texto se pasa de largo, y además para aclarar estoy usando angular no se si tendrá que ver algo ahí ya que estoy importando desde el index.

Comment: debes agregar el código o un ejemplo para poder ayudarte.